# How to define common dependencies in Gradle kotlin dsl from the parent project?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am setting up a multi module Gradle build with the Kotlin DSL. Below is the top level `build.gradle.kts` file I am using.

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    group = "com.example"
    version = "1.0.0"

    plugins.withType<JavaPlugin> {
        extensions.configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

            dependencies {
                implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.2.RELEASE"))
            }

            tasks.withType<Test> {
                useJUnitPlatform()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 15:                 implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.2.RELEASE"))
                           ^ Unresolved reference: implementation

1 error
```

**Question**

- How do I set common dependencies from the root `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: Regarding your second question, what exactly is it that you're struggling with? It seems this could be solved with a `"api"(...)` dependency just like the `"implementation"(...)`.

Comment: just removed the question you are right it's not clear just confusion my parts getting going with Gradle with no experience or knowledge of Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to read the [Gradle Kotlin DSL Primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:accessor_applicability). The section "Understanding when type-safe model accessors are available" explains why you shouldn't expect `implementation` to be defined at this place (emphasis mine):

> The set of type-safe model accessors available **is calculated right before evaluating the script body, immediately after the plugins {} block. Any model elements contributed after that point do not work with type-safe model accessors.** For example, this includes any configurations you might define in your own build script.

So you cannot use a typesafe accessor for `implementation` in the top-level `build.gradle`, except if you would apply the `java` plugin in its `plugins {}` block (which is not advised, unless the root project itself contains sources).

Instead, **use unsafe accessors, as demonstrated in the section [Understanding what to do when type-safe model accessors are not available](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_using_standard_api)**, like this:

```
plugins.withType<JavaPlugin> {
        extensions.configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

            dependencies {
                "implementation"(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.2.RELEASE"))
            }

            tasks.withType<Test> {
                useJUnitPlatform()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it mean common settings like `repositories` can't be defined in the root build file if using Kotlin DSL? Seems that way.